# search function in yii gridview

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I have project implemented in Yii. Grid view search function is not working in server. In localhost Grid view search function is working. What could be issue in that.  please suggest me where should i change.

my Recipe controller:

```
public function actionAdmin()
{   

    $model=new Recipe('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if(isset($_GET['Recipe']))
    $model->attributes=$_GET['Recipe'];

    $this->render('admin',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

My model part:

```
public function search()
{
    // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
    // should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
               $pagination=array('pageSize'=>'10'); 
    $criteria->compare('recipe_id',$this->recipe_id);
    $criteria->compare('posted_id',$this->posted_id,true);
    $criteria->compare('name',$this->name,true);
    $criteria->compare('type',$this->type);
    $criteria->compare('cuisinename',$this->cuisinename);
    $criteria->compare('course_id',$this->course_id);
    $criteria->compare('details',$this->details,true);
    $criteria->compare('serving_size',$this->serving_size,true);
    $criteria->compare('calorie_count',$this->calorie_count);
    $criteria->compare('preparation_time',$this->preparation_time);
    $criteria->compare('cooking_instructions',$this->cooking_instructions,true);
    $criteria->compare('garnishing_instructions',$this->garnishing_instructions,true);
    $criteria->compare('serving_instructions',$this->serving_instructions,true);
    $criteria->compare('recipe_image',$this->recipe_image,true);
    $criteria->compare('recipe_small_image',$this->recipe_small_image,true);
    $criteria->compare('status',$this->status,true);
    $criteria->compare('posting_time',$this->posting_time,true);
    $criteria->compare('pLike',$this->pLike);
    $criteria->compare('pDislike',$this->pDislike);
    $criteria->compare('images',$this->images,true);
    $criteria->compare('Ingredient_TypeId',$this->Ingredient_TypeId,true);


    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,'pagination'=>$pagination
    ));
}
```

my view part:

```
   <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(     'id'=>'mygridview',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
    //'id',
    'name',
    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn','template'=>'{update}{delete}',
    ),
   ),
)); ?>
```

Comment: post your `controller` + `model->seaarch()` + `grid` codes, so we can help you

Comment: i did exactly but. it works only localhost. it may issue in jquery or assests.

Comment: any error or javascript error you get in firebug??

Comment: event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. warning only am getting

Comment: i need to change in model search function

Comment: where could error pl help me

Comment: you were probably developing in windows and your host in linux, the problem might be with files case sensativity.

Comment: am developing my project in linux and localhost, server also in linux

Comment: i found error. am using jquery version jquery-2.0.3. these jquery collosion with bootstrap js ie assests/4193f952/jquery.min.js has collison with others. please suggest me how to overcome these issue

Answer (score 0):

Handle your javascript following way, there will be no double jquery problem after this, add all other js in the `'js'` array

```
$baseurl = Yii::app()->baseUrl;

$cs = Yii::app()->clientScript;
$cs->scriptMap = array('jquery.min.js'=>$baseurl.'/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js', 'jquery.js'=>$baseurl.'/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js');
$cs->registerCoreScript('jquery');

Yii::app()->clientScript->addPackage('other-required-scripts', array(
    'baseUrl'=>$baseurl,
    'js'=>array(
        "js/abc.js",
        "js/bcd.js",
        //...
    ),
   'depends'=>array('jquery')
));

Yii::app()->clientScript->registerPackage('other-required-scripts');
```